Definite integrals with closed forms involving q-analogs of functions
I was investigating the integral $$\lim_\limits{n\to\infty}\int_0^1 x+x^2+x^4+x^8+\dots+x^{2^n}\mathrm{d}x$$
and found it to be equal to $$\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{1}{2^n+1}=\frac{\psi_{1/4}(1)-\psi_{1/2}(1)-\ln(3)}{\ln(2)}-\frac{3}{2}$$
where $\psi_q(z)$ is the q-digamma function, the logarithmic derivative of the q-gamma function $\Gamma_q(z)$.
Are there other "nice" integrals that can be evaluated in terms of q-analogs of functions?

The boring answer is: "Yes, $q$-analogs have derivatives, so can be obtained by integration.  Those derivatives also have representations as various infinite series, infinite products, and so on, some of which should qualify as 'nice' integrals."

But $x^{2^0}=x^1=x.$ Am I wrong?
